# Reverse Engineering asp.net web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, reverse-engineering, reflector

I have an asp.net web application.  I don't have the source code.  The bin contains 10 assemblies and a .compiled file.  I used Reflector on the App_Code.dll and it shows me classes and namespaces and stuff, but its such a mess.

Is there any way to reverse engineer this web app that won't take weeks/months to unfold?  The application is pretty basic.

Note, the code is written by an engineer that left the company.  We own the product.

Comment: Is calling the guy up and asking where the source is out of the question?

Comment: How about access to his old computer?

Comment: @Bill MaGriff - yes, sadly.  And I don't even want to suggest suing anybody.  I'll leave those kinds of things up to my boss and Legal.  I'm just trying to do what I can to get us rolling again with this application.

Comment: @Bill MaGriff - That's a good idea.  They said they searched it and couldn't find his files.  This all happened well before I started here, like years ago.  I don't even know all the details.

Comment: Well if they didn't format it perhaps file recovery software can lend a hand. If you could find a debug dll you might be in business without having to sift through obfuscated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With reflector you can save the reflected code out to a project which you can load up in Visual Studio. It´s probably your best choice.

What you see is what you get and you just have to wade thru it in order to understand what´s going on in the program. Reading code is no free lunch.

Comment: I just dissambled part of it.  One of the files is called "DotfuscatorAttribute.cs".  All the files are called a.cs, b.cs...It looks like this guy took some trouble to make sure we couldn't easily get this resolved...

Comment: If the code is obfuscated you will have a harder time puzzling it back together. Variables will be hard to read and the project won´t compile in VS without a lot of editing. Maybe suing the old guy is the quickest solution as mentioned here, and be sure to add a source control system for all new development.

Comment: We have source control.  This company is just so huge that politics got in the way and we ended up with an angry engineer (he took one class on programming and wrote this cause the previous guy that ran dev just didnt do his job).  Anyways, yup here we are.  I don't think he obfuscated, that assembly was part of .NET.  All the assems in the form ASP_Web_* are readable and the app_code is too.  It looks like a PITA, but I guess this is the best that can be done.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately if you don't have the source code, you have one of 3 options:

- Reflector
- Rewrite
- Sue the original dev to give you the source code that you own (IANAL, so YMMV)