# Is it possible to reverse engineer decompiled C# code that has become jumbled during the decompiling process?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been put in charge of a project that we use at work that is done in C#/ASP.net, but the person working on the project before me didn't back up any of his source anywhere beyond his local machine and that machine is no longer operational, leaving me with basically no source code to work with. I've used dotPeek/dnSpy to attempt to get some of the code in a readable format, but many of the decompiled files have compiler-generated code that is more or less unreadable.

For example:

```
if (_Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.<Execute>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site3 == null)
{
                _Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.<Execute>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site3 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>.Create(Binder.BinaryOperation(CSharpBinderFlags.None, ExpressionType.NotEqual, typeof(_Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml), new CSharpArgumentInfo[]
                {
                    CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
                    CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.Constant, null)
}
```

Is there any way to figure out what these compiler-generated bits are trying to accomplish and rewrite them to try and recover all of the source, or am I just better off ripping it down and starting over?

Comment: No.  Without the source code that's the best you'll get.  Can you not even access the HDD from the dead PC?

Comment: So what I meant; the outputted code can be, at least manually converted. Which is a pretty hard job but doable for little pieces.

Comment: @Archer, unfortunately, no. The IT department literally just trashed the entire box. The only code I have to work with is what I've been able to decompile by pulling the code from the server it's hosted on.

Comment: In that case, the only real suggestion I can make that may help is to step through the code in debug mode and try and figure out what everything should be called.  That *may* help clarify it, but may be too big a job.  If the requirements are clear you may be better off just biting the bullet and spending that time rebuilding it.  And get some source control!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse Engineering asp.net web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020995/reverse-engineering-asp-net-web-app)

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question!  I've run into similar situations over the course of my career.  dotPeek is great for decompiling code, but definitely has some limitations.

I found this similar question here:  [Reverse Engineering asp.net web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020995/reverse-engineering-asp-net-web-app)

Sounds like Reflector is a possible option for what you need to do, if you are not able to recover the original source.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-306627.NETReflectorVisualStudioExtension

It is probably even better to understand what the application is doing and just rewrite the components that aren't easily decompiled, keeping what you are able from a functionality standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, unfortunately, no. It's going to involve some renaming of variables, methods and properties for you. At least the code doesn't seem like it has been obfuscated which would have made it trickier for you.